Remix and React.lazy "Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating."
I have a Remix app with this "/" route.
import React from 'react'
import { type LoaderFunction, json } from '@remix-run/node'
import { useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react'

const LandingPage = React.lazy(() => import('./LandingPage'))
const LatestEventsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./LatestEventsPage'))

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ context }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = Boolean(context.user)

  return json({
    isAuthenticated,
  })
}

const MainPage = () => {
  const loaderData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()

  if (!loaderData.isAuthenticated) {
    return <LandingPage />
  }

  return <LatestEventsPage />
}

export default MainPage

And a root.tsx like this
import { Global } from '@emotion/react'
import {
  Links,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from '@remix-run/react'
import { Suspense, useContext } from 'react'

export function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>{children}</Suspense>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return <Outlet />
}

When I go to "/", the screen flickers and I get this error:

Uncaught Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it
finished hydrating. This caused the boundary to switch to client
rendering. The usual way to fix this is to wrap the original update in
startTransition.

If I replace React.lazy with direct imports like this
// const LandingPage = React.lazy(() => import('./LandingPage'))
// const LatestEventsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./LatestEventsPage'))

import LandingPage from './LandingPage'
import LatestEventsPage from './LatestEventsPage'

But now I'm loading dead code. How do I fix this?
I used this for reference https://sergiodxa.com/tutorials/lazy-load-react-components-in-remix

I've had a similar issue and ended up removing Suspense entirely. If you're getting data from a loader and its awaited then you don't need suspense, however if its not awaited then I recommend using remix Await. The error seems to happen when suspense is wrapped around a route that will fetch its own data, this seems to conflict.
